# scala, transform a callback pattern to a functional style internal iterator

Tags: scala, scala-collections

Suppose this API is given and we cannot change it:

```
object ProviderAPI {

  trait Receiver[T] {
    def receive(entry: T)
    def close()
  }

  def run(r: Receiver[Int]) {
    new Thread() {
      override def run() {
        (0 to 9).foreach { i =>
          r.receive(i)
          Thread.sleep(100)
        }
        r.close()
      }
    }.start()
  }
}
```

In this example, `ProviderAPI.run` takes a `Receiver`, calls `receive(i)` 10 times and then closes. Typically, `ProviderAPI.run` would call `receive(i)` based on a collection which could be infinite.

This API is intended to be used in imperative style, like an external iterator. If our application needs to filter, map and print this input, we need to implement a Receiver which mixes all these operations:

```
object Main extends App {
  class MyReceiver extends ProviderAPI.Receiver[Int] {
    def receive(entry: Int) {
      if (entry % 2 == 0) {
        println("Entry#" + entry)
      }
    }
    def close() {}
  }

  ProviderAPI.run(new MyReceiver())
}
```

Now, the question is how to use the ProviderAPI in functional style, internal iterator (without changing the implementation of ProviderAPI, which is given to us). Note that ProviderAPI could also call `receive(i)` infinite times, so it is not an option to collect everything in a list (also, we should handle each result one by one, instead of collecting all the input first, and processing it afterwards).

I am asking how to implement such a `ReceiverToIterator`, so that we can use the ProviderAPI in functional style:

```
object Main extends App {
  val iterator = new ReceiverToIterator[Int]  // how to implement this?
  ProviderAPI.run(iterator)
  iterator
    .view
    .filter(_ % 2 == 0)
    .map("Entry#" + _)
    .foreach(println)
}
```

**Update**

Here are four solutions:

- [IteratorWithSemaphorSolution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38815226/280393): The workaround solution I proposed first attached to the question
- [QueueIteratorSolution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38814728/280393): Using the `BlockingQueue[Option[T]]` based on the suggestion of nadavwr.
  It allows the producer to continue producing up to `queueCapacity` before being blocked by the consumer.
- [PublishSubjectSolution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20391984/280393): Very simple solution, using `PublishSubject` from Netflix RxJava-Scala API.
- [SameThreadReceiverToTraversable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38798870/280393): Very simple solution, by relaxing the constraints of the question

Comment: Perhaps this reference will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7553270/is-there-a-fifo-stream-in-scala

Comment: Maybe you can use actors to do that...

Comment: @gzm0 I think he's really interested in achieving the example in the last block of code: `myReceiver.filter(...).map(...).foreach(...)`. How would you accomplish such a thing with an actor?

Comment: @nadavwr I mean actors inside the iterator to get rid of all the semaphore clutter. But the `BlockingQueue` of size 1 does the job very well. (except for EOF ;))

Comment: code: https://gist.github.com/dportabella/5766099

Comment: blog entry about this: http://scalaenthusiast.wordpress.com/2013/06/12/transform-a-callback-function-to-an-iteratorlist-in-scala/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Updated: BlockingQueue of 1 entry

What you've implemented here is essentially Java's BlockingQueue, with a queue size of 1.

Main characteristic: uber-blocking. A slow consumer will kill your producer's performance.

**Update:** @gzm0 mentioned that BlockingQueue doesn't cover EOF. You'll have to use BlockingQueue[Option[T]] for that.

**Update:** Here's a code fragment. It can be made to fit with your `Receiver`.
Some of it inspired by `Iterator.buffered`. Note that `peek` is a misleading name, as it may block -- and so will `hasNext`.

```
// fairness enabled -- you probably want to preserve order...
// alternatively, disable fairness and increase buffer to be 'big enough'
private val queue = new java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue[Option[T]](1, true)

// the following block provides you with a potentially blocking peek operation
// it should `queue.take` when the previous peeked head has been invalidated
// specifically, it will `queue.take` and block when the queue is empty
private var head: Option[T] = _
private var headDefined: Boolean = false
private def invalidateHead() { headDefined = false }
private def peek: Option[T] = {
  if (!headDefined) {
    head = queue.take()
    headDefined = true
  }
  head
}

def iterator = new Iterator[T] {

  // potentially blocking; only false upon taking `None`
  def hasNext = peek.isDefined

  // peeks and invalidates head; throws NoSuchElementException as appropriate
  def next: T = {
    val opt = peek; invalidateHead()
    if (opt.isEmpty) throw new NoSuchElementException
    else opt.get
  }
}
```

---

## Alternative: Iteratees

Iterator-based solutions will generally involve more blocking. Conceptually, you could use continuations on the thread doing the iteration to avoid blocking the thread, but continuations mess with Scala's for-comprehensions, so no joy down that road.

Alternatively, you could consider an iteratee-based solution. Iteratees are different than iterators in that the consumer isn't responsible for advancing the iteration -- the producer is. With iteratees, the consumer basically folds over the entries pushed by the producer over time. Folding each next entry as it becomes available can take place in a thread pool, since the thread is relinquished after each fold completes.

You won't get nice for-syntax for iteration, and the learning curve is a little challenging, but if you feel confident using a `foldLeft` you'll end up with a non-blocking solution that does look reasonable on the eye.

To read more about iteratees, I suggest taking a peek at [PlayFramework 2.X's iteratee reference](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/Iteratees). The documentation describes their stand-alone iteratee library, which is 100% usable outside the context of Play. Scalaz 7 also has a comprehensive iteratee library.

Comment: the BlockingQueue[Option[T]] seems a good solution; I'll try this out and come back. About the iteratees, i got a headache reading the play2 reference, but it seems quite interesting. i'll look for a better tutorial and try it out. thanks.

Comment: I've updated the question using BlockingQueue[Option[T]] as you suggested. the solution i found is still quite long and not very nice. did you have a better solution in mind?

Comment: Reusing BlockingQueue should allow you to produce much shorter code. IIRC, Java's BlockingQueue implements Iterable, which can be transformed to a Scala Iterable using decorateAsScala.  From then on you can get your Scala Iterator in a single call. You'd just have to transform the Option into a flat next() -- hasNext should still rely on the option, of course.

Comment: i tried to use the BlockingQueue iterator, but it does not work out with the eof. i've updated the question with the last implementation that i managed to do using BlockingQueue. it's still pretty long.

Comment: @DavidPortabella Sorry for the headache. There are other tutorials that may work better for you, but it's definitely a complicated topic. Complexity and high overhead (when dealing with lots of small chunks) are the main disadvantage for iteratees, though they do have their sweet spot performance-wise.

Comment: @DavidPortabella I still suggest sticking mostly to Play's iteratee documentation, since their implementation has the best documentation and the most examples, and is the easiest to pick up and use.

Answer (score 0):

**PublishSubjectSolution**

A very simple solution using `PublishSubject` from Netflix RxJava-Scala API:

```
// libraryDependencies += "com.netflix.rxjava" % "rxjava-scala" % "0.20.7"

import rx.lang.scala.subjects.PublishSubject

class MyReceiver[T] extends ProviderAPI.Receiver[T] {
  val channel = PublishSubject[T]()
  def receive(entry: T) { channel.onNext(entry) }
  def close() { channel.onCompleted() }
}

object Main extends App {
  val myReceiver = new MyReceiver[Int]()
  ProviderAPI.run(myReceiver)
  myReceiver.channel.filter(_ % 2 == 0).map("Entry#" + _).subscribe{n => println(n)}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**ReceiverToTraversable**

This stackoverflow question came when I wanted to list and process a svn repository using the svnkit.com API as follows:

```
SvnList svnList = new SvnOperationFactory().createList();
svnList.setReceiver(new ISvnObjectReceiver<SVNDirEntry>() {
  public void receive(SvnTarget target, SVNDirEntry dirEntry) throws SVNException {
    // do something with dirEntry
  }
});
svnList.run();
```

the API used a callback function, and I wanted to use a functional style instead, as follows:

```
svnList.
  .filter(e => "pom.xml".compareToIgnoreCase(e.getName()) == 0)
  .map(_.getURL)
  .map(getMavenArtifact)
  .foreach(insertArtifact)
```

I thought of having a class `ReceiverToIterator[T]` extends `ProviderAPI.Receiver[T]` with `Iterator[T]`,
but this required the svnkit api to run in another thread.
That's why I asked how to solve this problem with a ProviderAPI.run method that run in a new thread. But that was not very wise: **if I had explained the real case, someone might have found a better solution before**.

**Solution**

If we tackle the real problem (so, no need of using a thread for the svnkit),
a simpler solution is to implement a `scala.collection.Traversable` instead of a `scala.collection.Iterator`.
While `Iterator` requires a `next` and `hasNext` def, `Traversable` requires a `foreach` def,
which is very similar to the svnkit callback!

Note that by using `view`, we make the transformers lazy, so elements are passed one by one through all the chain to `foreach(println)`.
this allows to process an infinite collection.

```
object ProviderAPI {
  trait Receiver[T] {
    def receive(entry: T)
    def close()
  }

  // Later I found out that I don't need a thread
  def run(r: Receiver[Int]) {
    (0 to 9).foreach { i => r.receive(i); Thread.sleep(100) }
  }
}

object Main extends App {
  new ReceiverToTraversable[Int](r => ProviderAPI.run(r))
    .view
    .filter(_ % 2 == 0)
    .map("Entry#" + _)
    .foreach(println)
}

class ReceiverToTraversable[T](val runProducer: (ProviderAPI.Receiver[T] => Unit)) extends Traversable[T] {
  override def foreach[U](f: (T) => U) = {
    object MyReceiver extends ProviderAPI.Receiver[T] {
      def receive(entry: T) = f(entry)
      def close() = {}
    }
    runProducer(MyReceiver)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**QueueIteratorSolution**

The second workaround solution that I proposed attached to the question. I moved it here as an answer.

Solution using the `BlockingQueue[Option[T]]` based on the suggestion of nadavwr.
It allows the producer to continue producing up to `queueCapacity` before being blocked by the consumer.
I implement a QueueToIterator that uses a `ArrayBlockingQueue` with a given capacity.
BlockingQueue has a `take()` method, but not a `peek` or `hasNext`, so I need an `OptionNextToIterator` as follows:

```
trait OptionNextToIterator[T] extends Iterator[T] {
  def getOptionNext: Option[T]   // abstract
  def hasNext = { ... }
  def next = { ... }
}
```

Note: I am using the `synchronized` block inside `OptionNextToIterator`, and I am not sure it is totally correct

**Solution:**

```
import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue

object Main extends App {
  val receiverToIterator = new ReceiverToIterator[Int](queueCapacity = 3)
  ProviderAPI.run(receiverToIterator)

  Thread.sleep(3000)  // test that ProviderAPI.run can produce 3 items ahead before being blocked by the consumer
  receiverToIterator.filter(_ % 2 == 0).map("Entry#" + _).foreach(println)
}

class ReceiverToIterator[T](val queueCapacity: Int = 1) extends ProviderAPI.Receiver[T] with QueueToIterator[T] {
  def receive(entry: T) { queuePut(entry) }
  def close() { queueClose() }
}

trait QueueToIterator[T] extends OptionNextToIterator[T] {
  val queueCapacity: Int
  val queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue[Option[T]](queueCapacity)
  var queueClosed = false

  def queuePut(entry: T) {
    if (queueClosed) { throw new IllegalStateException("The queue has already been closed."); }
    queue.put(Some(entry))
  }

  def queueClose() {
    queueClosed = true
    queue.put(None)
  }

  def getOptionNext = queue.take
}

trait OptionNextToIterator[T] extends Iterator[T] {
  def getOptionNext: Option[T]

  var answerReady: Boolean = false
  var eof: Boolean = false
  var element: T = _

  def hasNext = {
    prepareNextAnswerIfNecessary()
    !eof
  }

  def next = {
    prepareNextAnswerIfNecessary()
    if (eof) { throw new NoSuchElementException }
    val retVal = element
    answerReady = false
    retVal
  }

  def prepareNextAnswerIfNecessary() {
    if (answerReady) {
      return
    }
    synchronized {
      getOptionNext match {
        case None => eof = true
        case Some(e) => element = e
      }
      answerReady = true
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**IteratorWithSemaphorSolution**

The first workaround solution that I proposed attached to the question.
I moved it here as an answer.

```
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore

object Main extends App {
  val iterator = new ReceiverToIterator[Int]
  ProviderAPI.run(iterator)
  iterator
    .filter(_ % 2 == 0)
    .map("Entry#" + _)
    .foreach(println)
}

class ReceiverToIterator[T] extends ProviderAPI.Receiver[T] with Iterator[T] {
  var lastEntry: T = _
  var waitingToReceive = new Semaphore(1)
  var waitingToBeConsumed = new Semaphore(1)
  var eof = false

  waitingToReceive.acquire()

  def receive(entry: T) {
    println("ReceiverToIterator.receive(" + entry + "). START.")
    waitingToBeConsumed.acquire()
    lastEntry = entry
    waitingToReceive.release()
    println("ReceiverToIterator.receive(" + entry + "). END.")
  }

  def close() {
    println("ReceiverToIterator.close().")
    eof = true
    waitingToReceive.release()
  }

  def hasNext = {
    println("ReceiverToIterator.hasNext().START.")
    waitingToReceive.acquire()
    waitingToReceive.release()
    println("ReceiverToIterator.hasNext().END.")
    !eof
  }

  def next = {
    println("ReceiverToIterator.next().START.")
    waitingToReceive.acquire()
    if (eof) { throw new NoSuchElementException }
    val entryToReturn = lastEntry
    waitingToBeConsumed.release()
    println("ReceiverToIterator.next().END.")
    entryToReturn
  }
}
```